# Selecting a range of values from each list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, filter

I have a list of list as follows

```
list_A = [[0.4,0.9,1,4,8],[9,2,3,7,8],[1,1.5,5,7,8],[5,6,10,2,3]]
```

I am interested in values that are between `a=1` and `b=4`, 1 and 4 included.

1. How can I select values from `list_A` that are in the range of interest (a and b)? I want to get the following output `list_B`:

```
list_B = [[1,4],[2,3],[1,1.5],[2,3]]
```

2. How can I record the index of selected values from from each list of lists of `list_A`? The output `list_C` should look like below

```
list_C = [[0,1],[1,2],[0,1],[3,4]]
```

3. How can I select values from `list_D` using index positions defined by `list_C`?

```
list_D = [[100,200,50,60,50],[5,20,30,45,50],[90,10,30,40,60],[30,40,50,20,10]]
```

so that my output `list_E` look like

```
list_E = [[100,200],[20,30],[90,10],[20,10]]
```

What I tried so far:

```
list_B = [i[a:b] for i in list_A]
```

But I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: I suppose the only way to go is to iterate over the lists and store indices as well as the elements at those indices as you go along that satisfy your condition. I don't think there is any other approach (at least that i know of) since the given nested list doesn't appear to be sorted or anything.

Comment: so ifI understand you are only interested in list_E ? or will you need the other ones, if not you can use list comprehension

Comment: I'm confused by `list_B` - you want numbers between 1 and 4, but your example shows `[0.2, 0.9]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by building a list of the selected items and their indexes using `enumerate` and a filter:

```
>>> list_A = [[0.4,0.9,1,4,8],[9,2,3,7,8],[1,1.5,5,7,8],[5,6,10,2,3]]
>>> a, b = 1, 4
>>> e = [[(i, n) for i, n in enumerate(x) if a <= n <= b] for x in list_A]
>>> e
[[(2, 1), (3, 4)], [(1, 2), (2, 3)], [(0, 1), (1, 1.5)], [(3, 2), (4, 3)]]
```

List B is just the items:

```
>>> [[n for _, n in x] for x in e]
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [1, 1.5], [2, 3]]
```

List C is just the indices (note that your expected output doesn't match this, but the indices of 1 and 4 are indeed 2 and 3, not 0 and 1):

```
>>> [[i for i, _ in x] for x in e]
[[2, 3], [1, 2], [0, 1], [3, 4]]
```

You can build list E by zipping C and D:

```
>>> list_C = [[i for i, _ in x] for x in e]
>>> list_D = [[100,200,50,60,50],[5,20,30,45,50],[90,10,30,40,60],[30,40,50,20,10]]
>>> [[d[i] for i in c] for c, d in zip(list_C, list_D)]
[[50, 60], [20, 30], [90, 10], [20, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Samwise, this is a great use for `zip`

My solution using comprehensions. If you anticipate having to do this multiple times, you could functionalize it fairly easily and return all your lists in a dictionary, for example.

```py
list_A = [[0.4,0.9,1,4,8],[9,2,3,7,8],[1,1.5,5,7,8],[5,6,10,2,3]]
a, b = 1, 4

# filter out numbers outside of your range
list_B = [[n for n in l if a <= n <=b] for l in list_A]
# use the index() method to get the indices of numbers in your range
list_C = [[l.index(n) for n in l if a <= n <= b] for l in list_A

list_D = [[100,200,50,60,50],[5,20,30,45,50],[90,10,30,40,60],[30,40,50,20,10]]
# zip list_C and list_D and filter via index
list_E = [[D[idx] for idx in C] for C, D in zip(list_C, list_D)]
```

Comment: Careful using `index` like this -- it'll always return the index of the first occurrence, which might mess you up if there are multiple occurrences of the same value.  Using `enumerate` avoids that problem by giving you the index of each individual occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You could `zip` `list_A` and `list_D` together and extract appropriate values in a list comprehension without the intermediate steps

```
[[d[i] for i, v in enumerate(a) if 1 <= v <= 4] for a, d in zip(list_A, list_D)]
# [[50, 60], [20, 30], [90, 10], [20, 10]]
```